# Gradle failed to clean output directory

Tags: java, gradle, grpc, gradlew, grpc-java

**Issue Description**
Running "gradle clean" failed to artifacts from project output directory. After enable *--stacktrace* I can see below error

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.file.UnableToDeleteFileException: Unable to delete file: C:\Users\xxxx\my-project-root\build\libs\some.jar
```

Here is my "gradle --version" output

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 5.1.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2019-01-10 23:05:02 UTC
Revision:     3c9abb645fb83932c44e8610642393ad62116807

Kotlin DSL:   1.1.1
Kotlin:       1.3.11
Groovy:       2.5.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.13 compiled on July 10 2018
JVM:          1.8.0_152 (Oracle Corporation 25.152-b16)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64
```

Initially my thought process was that some gradle daemon might be still be holding a reference to build artifacts. But after running "gradle --stop" I still get the same error for clean task.

Do note that if I open command prompt/powershell with **administrative mode** ":clean" tasks works fine.

I am not sure if anyone has faced this strange issue.

**Solution**
Please suggest if any.

Comment: Probaly JAR is used somewehere

Comment: Is it possible you compiled once as Administrator earlier? It would have generated that file and your normal user may not have permission to it. I'd expect that after a `gradle clean` and `gradle --stop` as Administrator you would be able to compile as a normal user.

Comment: @EricAnderson This solution actually works. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by Eric Anderson in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54488100/gradle-failed-to-clean-output-directory#comment95858531_54488100):

> Is it possible you compiled once as Administrator earlier? It would have generated that file and your normal user may not have permission to it. I'd expect that after a `gradle clean` and `gradle --stop` as Administrator you would be able to compile as a normal user.

I ran into this same problem after having done `sudo gradle run` earlier, and a `sudo gradle clean` fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

The file is likely open by another process. The easiest way to find the process keeping the file open is to use [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) and "Find a Handle or DLL". Search for the file name. Then close the processes listed.

If you prefer a command-line tool, execute [handle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle) like:

```
handle c:\path\to\file
```

Comment: Tried both of the above mentioned approach. Process Explorer says "0 matching items". And Handler says "No matching handlers found". Also i cant even delete it using windows **del** or **rm(MINGW)** . I got "Access is denied"